# R: How to generate all possible vectors of the form c(a,b,c) where a,b,c are integers and a < b < c <= 100?

Tags: r

Now I can get this jobs done using

```
x <- expand.grid(1:98, 1:99, 1:100);
x.subset <- subset(x, Var1 < Var2 & Var2 < Var3)
```

But is there a more elegant way? I think the step where x is created can be dropped. Imagine if I want to do this for a < b < c < 10,000. The expand grid would fail on lesser machines (I know x.subset would be humongous too!, but I have a better chance of creating it if I can skip the step where x is created.).

Comment: There is no way that up until 10,000 would fit into memory (9.997e+11 elements). I think you've got a pretty good version right here

Comment: What do you intend to do with these combinations?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that up until 10,000 would fit into memory (9998 * 9999 * 10000 == 9.997e+11 elements). Even a 1000 won't fit. I think you've got a pretty good version right here that performs fast for roughly up until 100, but going much above it simply won't be possible.

However, perhaps reconsider your "need" for this approach, and see if there might be another way to achieve it.

Comment: I'd give your final statement a "+100" .  Trust the `Data Munger Guru` (not me) when he says "tell me the problem you want solved, not how you want to solve it."

Comment: From where do you get the requirement that the 3 elements need to sum to 100? I don't see that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`combn` should be useful here. Example:

```
combn(1:4, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    2
#[2,]    2    2    3    3
#[3,]    3    4    4    4
```

However, up to 10.000 will still be problematic and there is probably some better algorithm to get to your final goal.

Comment: Interesting thought: can you run a time-benchmark of the OP's approach vs., say  `combn` followed by rejecting all columns which are not in ascending order?  something like `if (any(diff(order(column) )<0)...` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I believe `combn` already returns the the desired order. No post-processing required.

Comment: This approach is slower though than what `xiaodai` mentioned. Median time of 377.9203 vs 244.3379 milliseconds according to microbenchmark (neval=100).

Comment: @PascalvKooten My timings are 325.7292 for the code in the question vs. 270.1952 for `combn(1:100,3)`. I would be very surprised if `expand.grid` and `subset` were faster than `combn`.

Comment: I'm still reproducing the same results, http://pastebin.com/neXC3qzG. Perhaps the R / OS ? Ubuntu 13.04 R 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer for readability.  My timing shows cgrid winning.  R302, Windows7, i7 processor (single-core utilized, of course).

```
Rgames> cgrid <-function(x,y,z) {
+ x <- expand.grid(1:98, 1:99, 1:100);
+ x.subset <- subset(x, Var1 < Var2 & Var2 < Var3)
+ }
Rgames> ccomb<-function(z) combn(1:z,3)  
Rgames>  microbenchmark(cgrid(1:98,1:99,1:100),ccomb(100),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr        min         lq      median         uq
 cgrid(1:98, 1:99, 1:100) 217.330657 220.113192 253.5495825 325.167895
               ccomb(100) 336.545629 346.839341 358.8957100 380.154500
        max neval
 346.787171    10
 452.278904    10
```